# SimplePosttool: FATAL: specifying either url or core/collection is mandatory

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm new in solr and I want to start an example that is in the exampledocs folder , but when I try to start it using the windows prompt I have the error message in the title.
Someone can help me?

Answer (score 19):

When running the Solr Quick Start on Windows I faced the same problem. In the comments of the guide I found what worked for me:

```
C:\opt\solr-5.2.1>java -Dc=gettingstarted -jar example\exampledocs\post.jar example\exampledocs\*.xml
```

That got me the following output:

```
C:\opt\solr-5.2.1>java -Dc=gettingstarted -jar example\exampledocs\post.jar example\exampledocs\*.xml
SimplePostTool version 5.0.0
Posting files to [base] url http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update using content-type application/xml...
POSTing file gb18030-example.xml to [base]
POSTing file hd.xml to [base]
POSTing file ipod_other.xml to [base]
POSTing file ipod_video.xml to [base]
POSTing file manufacturers.xml to [base]
POSTing file mem.xml to [base]
POSTing file money.xml to [base]
POSTing file monitor.xml to [base]
POSTing file monitor2.xml to [base]
POSTing file mp500.xml to [base]
POSTing file sd500.xml to [base]
POSTing file solr.xml to [base]
POSTing file utf8-example.xml to [base]
POSTing file vidcard.xml to [base]
14 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update...
Time spent: 0:00:22.043
```

The `-Dc` parameter does the trick.

On the other hand when only running with the folder *docs* it did not work. But this is not scope of my answer since I only wanted to show how to get it running anyhow.

Comment: I tried this, SimplePostTool is running, but I'm getting lots of "HTTP error 404" instead of the "posting file" lines. I'm using the same version as you, not sure what's going on... I'll keep looking

Answer (score 4):

Start your [Solr Admin](http://localhost:8983/solr/#/)
Create one core using following command:

```
solr create -c <name>
```

Select core from **core_selector** dropdown

click on documents and then add data to be added in the core.Format of document can be specify by you.

**OR**

Type this command in solr-(versioname)\example\exampledocs

```
java -Dc=my_core -Dtype=text/csv -jar post.jar test.csv
```

where my_core is corename,
      type is csv and 
      test.csv is file to be imported.

Answer (score 2):

With version 5, the default collection has effectively gone away. So, there is no way for the tool to know which URL to use to connect to your collection.

If you are using examples, then your server is most probably default at localhost:8983 and you only need to specify the collection by name. If you are doing something more tricky, you may need to specify the whole URL.

Comment: Hi Alex, can you give an example?  Totally new to this myself. Im using the "gettingstarted" tutorial and I'm looking to post files into Solr for searching.  I should say that I am doing this on Windows.

Comment: Have you tried following the [Quick Start Guide](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/quickstart.html) ? It should get you through the most basic steps. You can see the collection *gettingstarted* in the examples there.

Answer (score 1):

Need to mention collection name, for new versions you can write simply this command.

```
bin/post -c gettingstarted example/exampledocs/*.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Executing a command line from tutorial below unix command line helped. I.e. on Windows and solr 5.4.1 my terminal line looked like

```
c:\solr-5.4.1> java -classpath dist/solr-core-5.4.1.jar -Dauto=yes 
    -Dc=gettingstarted -Ddata=files 
    -Drecursive=yes org.apache.solr.util.SimplePostTool docs/
```